# Problema na criação de uma stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Estou tentando criar uma stored procedure que sirva para verificar se minha tabela está vazia, e caso não esteja retornar o valor com o maior Id. Contudo não estou conseguindo.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spConsulta
@NameTable VARCHAR (50)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT Value
    FROM @NameTable
    WHERE Id = (SELECT MAX(Id) FROM @NameTable);

    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
        RETURN 0 
END
```

Errors.

Msg 1087, Nível 16, Estado 1, Procedimento spConsulta, Linha 6 [Linha de Início do Lote 0]
É necessário declarar a variável de tabela "@NameTable".
Msg 1087, Nível 16, Estado 1, Procedimento spConsulta, Linha 7 [Linha de Início do Lote 0]
É necessário declarar a variável de tabela "@NameTable".

Alguém saberia como resolver este problema ? Pelo visto o problema esta no @NameTable, estou fazendo desta forma pois estou tentando utilizar esta stored procedure para todas as tabelas, pois todas as tabelas possuem a mesma estrutura, pelo visto não esta funcionando. Alguém saberia alguma forma alternativa de fazer isto ?

Comment: ```-- Declare the variable to be used.
DECLARE @NamdTable AS varchar(50)``` https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/language-elements/variables-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 e https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que você esqueceu foi declarar a variável,o próprio console mostrou isso: `Msg 1087, Nível 16, Estado 1, Procedimento spConsulta, Linha 6 [Linha de Início do Lote 0] É necessário declarar a variável de tabela "@NameTable". Msg 1087, Nível 16, Estado 1, Procedimento spConsulta, Linha 7 [Linha de Início do Lote 0] É necessário declarar a variável de tabela "@NameTable".`

Solução:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE spConsulta
    @NameTable varchar(50)
AS      
BEGIN 
    SELECT Value,Id
    FROM NameTable
    WHERE Id = MAX(Id)
    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
        RETURN 0 
    END
```

Link úteis:

https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/language-elements/variables-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-local-variable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Eu tentei desta forma, contudo ele esta apontando error de sintax incorreta próximo à palavra-chave 'Declare' e 'AS'.

Comment: varchar(50)? Você entrou nos links?

Comment: @Levi tenta agora

Comment: Desta forma esta apontando o mesmo erro de declaração e também o error : o create/alter procedure deve ser o primeiro em um lote de consultas. Estou lendo os links neste exato momento, tentarei dar um feedback o quanto antes.

Comment: No meu nao está dando erro.

Comment: Tenta agora. Se nao funcionou me avisa.

Comment: Agora ele esta dando 'Value' e 'Id' como nome de coluna invalido, creio que não da pra fazer da forma que estou tentando. Estava fazendo desta forma, ("substituindo o nome da tabela por um varchar"), pois não queria criar um procedure para cada tabela. É possivel fazer uma procedure "genérica" ?

Comment: Pra mim ta indo normal. Eu não sei,eu uso sql server e nunca aconteceu cmg. Eu acho que é possível. Posso te manda um exemplo: https://www.devmedia.com.br/introducao-aos-stored-procedures-no-sql-server/7904